# Example of Schauder basis to $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C - \{0\}$ such that $0 < |\frac{\beta}{\alpha}| < 1$ and
$$
x_1 = (\alpha, \beta, 0,...), x_2 = (0, \alpha, \beta, 0,...), x_3 = (0, 0, \alpha, \beta, 0,...),...
$$
Show that $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is a Schauder basis of $\ell^2$.

I know that each $x_i$ could be written as follows
$$
x_i = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \alpha e_i + \beta e_{i+1}
$$
where $e_i$ represents the canonical vector with input 1 in the $i$ th coordinate and 0 in the rest, but I don't know how to use the condition of $0 < |\frac{\beta}{\alpha}| < 1$.

Comment: You need to converge to $e_n$.

Comment: that is, $|\frac{\beta}{\alpha}| \to 1, yes?$ but is a constant...

Comment: Why? What do you get when you want to express $e_i$ by $x_j$'s?

Comment: A base, no? I want to express every vector as a linear combination, i.e., $x=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \gamma_k e_k$ in this case, infinite linear combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\mathbf{e}_j=\delta_j$ ($1$ in the $j$-th component, zero otherwise).
Since for any  $\mathbf{x}\in\ell_2$, $\mathbf{x}=\sum^\infty_{j=1}\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{e}_j\rangle \mathbf{e}_i$,
it is enough to show that each $\mathbf{e}_j$ is of the form $\sum_k a_{jk}\mathbf{x}_k$.

\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{e}_1&=\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{x}_1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\mathbf{e}_2\\
\mathbf{e}_2&=\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{x}_2-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\mathbf{e}_3\\
&\ldots\\
\mathbf{e}_j&=\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{x}_j-\frac{\beta}
{\alpha}\mathbf{e}_{j+1}\\
\ldots
\end{aligned}

By induction

$$ \mathbf{e}_1 = \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum^N_{j=1}\big(-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\big)^{j-1}\mathbf{x}_j +\big(-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\big)^N\mathbf{e}_{N+1}
$$

From this and the assumption $0<|\beta/\alpha|<1$, one can see that $\mathbf{e}_1$ has the desired expression. Similar procedure for other $\mathbf{e}_j$'s.

Comment: I understand that this is just a hint, but simply showing that each $e_i$ can be expressed in terms of the $x_i$ does not make $\{x_i\}_i$ a Schauder basis.  In other words, a lot more work is needed.

Comment: forget the previous comment.The next step would be to find the norm of $e_1$ minus the sum, which gives zero, but since you find the scalars so that for $ v \in \ell^2$ the two norm of $v$ minus the sum gives zero?